# What is the domain of $({\sqrt x})^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratic-forms

I have the following question with me:

> Find the middle point of solution of the inequality.$$x^2+2(\sqrt x)^2-3\le0$$

I went through the following process:
$$x^2+2x-3\le0$$
$$(x+3)(x-1)\le0$$
$$x\in[-3,1]$$
But $$\sqrt x\ge0\implies x\ge0$$
So, $$x\in[0,1]$$
After I went through the question again, I pointed out that the negative numbers also satisfy the inequality. I asked my teacher but he said that square of a number can't give you a negative number if we are working in $\Bbb R$. I understood that this is possible when we work in Complex numbers but the problem is that Wolfram too is showing the domain of x to be $[-3,1]$ and the graph of this inequality also confirms it. When I checked for the domain of $(\sqrt x)^2$ in Wolfram Alpha then it showed $x\ge0$. So, I have been confused as to what should I consider the solution and what not to if we are working in Real Numbers' Domain?

Comment: Which question did you ask WolframAlpha whose answer made you think that, according to WolframAlpha, the domain of $x$ is $[-3,1]$?

Comment: I put into Wolfram the exact inequality written at the first.

Comment: $\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2 = (f \circ g)(x)$ where $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$. The domain of $f \circ g$ is the domain of $g$.

Comment: As far as WolframAlpha is concerned, $\sqrt x$ exists for every complex number $x$ and it is defined in such a way that we always have $\sqrt x^2=x$. But then $\sqrt x\notin\Bbb R$ when $x\in(-\infty,0]$. So, what WolframAlpha tells you shouldn't be taken literally when you are working with real numbers only.

Comment: The domain is the set of non-negative real numbers since $\sqrt{x}$ is not defined for negative real numbers , unless you allow complex square roots which is apparently not intented.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you so much. So it means that although the graph says otherwise but we should stick to what we have defined and keep the domain of $x$ to be $[0,1]$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Slight correction : For $x=0$ , the real square root is defined. So, the right bracket must be ")"

Comment: The *answer* is $[0,1]$; I don't see why is it that you call it “domain”. And the graph that WolframAlpha provides is based upon the assumption that you have $\sqrt x^2=x$, for each $x\in\Bbb R$, which doesn't hold if you work only with real numbers.

Comment: @Peter Right. Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you so much for providing clarification. I am sorry I couldn't get you, if domain is not the right word here then what is it, kindly tell.

Comment: I would say that the set of solutions of your inequality is $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative numbers do *not* satisfy the inequality for the reason that your teacher said. So any "solution" for $x < 0$ is not valid, and the domain of $(\sqrt{x})^2$ is hence $x \geq 0$. The solution of the inequality is hence [0, 1]. This is assuming we are working in the real space.

> and the graph of this inequality also confirms it

Desmos does not support that statement:

[image: graph of problem in Desmos]

Comment: Thank you so much!